# Flash Video Spokesperson in Wordpress => Tweople

Tags: javascript, wordpress, flash, cross-domain, html5-video

I am developing a Wordpress site for a manufacturing company. The company would like to have a Video Spokesperson on some of the pages. Specifically we are testing it here: http://beautifulimage.net/test-magazine
The scripts that they provide are here: http://tweople.com/client/embed/1401121859b

Unfortunately, the video will only play once (with one iteration of the script) or not at all. For the iteration that will play it, you can refresh the cookies and it will play again.

1) I started by following the documentation that was provided. I expressly followed every direction implicitly without consistent success (it worked occasionally on http) ... I verified that the script/video works on 3 other sites (not secured sites), which further confirms that their product does work, but that there is a conflict. This conflict maybe with scripts that we are using on our site or with cross domain calls, but it is definitely not working the way that it should be.

2) Upon realizing that the script doesn't work on our site. I went through extensive troubleshooting.

Here are major trouble shooting errors I went through:

- creating a cross domain xml file (recommended by adobe)
  for registering flash videos that can be cross domain using 3rd
  partyflash player
- trying the video as an html5 video alone (no    transparency. the
  background was white)
- going through the initiation/video player script to see if I need to
  hard code links
- support withtwepeople email
- deactivating all WP plugins that could be causing conflicts and testing all previous debugging measures
- I asked mediatemple (hosting company) if there was anything in the hosting account that could be causing the error.

note: The javascript console was calling out cross domain errors when we were occasionally getting it to work on http. When I forced https the video spokesperson stopped working completely.

I currently have multiple scripts inside of the file (lines 406, one commented out). The company has been attempting to support the issue, but have been unable to.

Anything to help is appreciated.

Comment: I tested your link and it's working fine on firefox, chrome and opera ! For your case, you don't need a crossdomain.xml file because the player and its loaded content are in the same domain. So could you give us more details about the problem when it's fired using the browser network logging tab ?

Comment: So the error is in consistent. But the video won't show up unless you refresh the cookies, or you are looking at it for the first time (this link: http://beautifulimage.net/test-magazine )... the second link was the source

Comment: No, I tried it many times without refreshing the cookies and it's working well !